# Can't get gravity to work with RMagick and 'caption'

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, rmagick

I'm using RMagick 2.12.2 with ImageMagick 6.5.6-10 on Snow Leopard. I'm trying to put captions on a collection of photos, and I'm getting the caption to work (i.e. it appears on the image), but I can't get the gravity parameter to work correctly.

No matter what I set it to, I end up with some variation on NorthGravity.

For instance: Setting it to SouthWestGravity gives me NorthWestGravity.  Setting it to SouthEastGravity gives me NorthEastGravity.  Setting it to CenterGravity gives me NorthGravity.

In other words, I can't get the caption to come down off the top of the image.

I'd consider using "annotate," but I need "caption" so the lengthy caption text for each image will wrap.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require "rubygems"
require "yaml"
require "RMagick"
include Magick

base_dir = "/Users/mike/Desktop/caption_test"

photo_log = File.open("#{base_dir}/photo_log.yaml" )

YAML::load_documents(photo_log) do |doc|

  caption = doc["photo-caption"]
  filename = doc["file"]

  canvas = ImageList.new.from_blob(open("#{base_dir}/#{filename}") { |f| f.read } )

  canvas << Magick::Image.read("caption:#{caption}") { 
  self.gravity = SouthWestGravity
  self.size = "#{canvas.first.columns}"
  self.font = "Helvetica Neue"
  self.pointsize = 12
  self.background_color = "#fff"
 }.first

 canvas.flatten_images.write("#{base_dir}/images/#{filename}")

end
```

Comment: Did you [remember](http://xkcd.com/353/) to `import antigravity` ... sorry wrong language.

Answer (score 1):

You've probably long since moved on, but the I found a pretty simple answer to this--use

```
canvas.append(true).write("#{base_dir}/images/#{filename}")
```

In other words, you want the append option (use 'true' to stack vertically).

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you're applying the gravity to the dimensions of the caption image rather than the dimensions of the underlying image. Your caption will East/West align itself within its width but because it makes it own height, North/South always just mean North.

You probably want to specify the gravity on the flatten_images call instead which looks possible...